# Does clang support format string %ms so scanf() allocates the buffer?

Tags: c, clang, scanf

Should `scanf("%ms", &s)` work in clang?

app.c:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *s;
    int ret = scanf("%ms", &s);
    if (ret) {
      printf("%d %s\n", ret, s);
      free(s);
    }
    else {
      printf("NO!\n");
    }
}
```

```sh
$ clang ./app.c && echo abc | ./a.out
NO!
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
```

Same results with the `gcc` installed on my macOS, but it seems to using clang internally.

On Linux using `gcc`, scanf succeeded:

```
1 abc
```

From [gcc man scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> ```
>   Each conversion specification in format begins with either the
>   character '%' or the character sequence "%n$" (see below for the
>   distinction) followed by:
>    -     An optional 'm' character.  This is used with string
>          conversions (%s, %c, %[), and relieves the caller of the
>          need to allocate a corresponding buffer to hold the input:
>          instead, scanf() allocates a buffer of sufficient size,
>          and assigns the address of this buffer to the
>          corresponding pointer argument, which should be a pointer
>          to a char * variable (this variable does not need to be
>          initialized before the call).  The caller should
>          subsequently free(3) this buffer when it is no longer
>          required.
> ```

This is confusing because if I break the type by removing the second arg `&` then clang gives a warning; it recognizes that `%ms` needs a pointer to a `char*`:

```
./app.c:5:28: warning: format specifies type 'char **' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
    int ret = scanf("%ms", s);
                     ~~~   ^
                     %s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) is not [the C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations). It's way more diversified. `clang`, `gcc`, `msvc` and others are compilers. `glibc`, `musl` and others are C standard library implementations, and *they* come with `scanf()` function implementation and may or may not support `%m` assignment-allocation character extension. The `%m` is non-standard, as in it is not specified in [the C language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects).

> Does clang support format string %ms so scanf() allocates the buffer?

`clang` is a compiler, it compiles code. In a literal sense of the question, `clang` supports passing anything to `scanf()` function, including any format specifiers. `clang` compiles the code and creates an executable.

As you also found out, `clang` as a compiler supports diagnosing the case, when an invalid parameter type is provided for `%ms` `scanf` format specifier. In that sense, `clang` warnings support this format specifier.

Let's say, the question "if clang supports `%m` specifier" is like asking if a car tire can drive fast. Well, literally it can, but it depends on the engine (the C standard library) if your car will be fast or not (support the specifier or not). (Bad allegory, but hope it just illustrates the point of the answer).

> on my macOS

As I understand, the BSD libc C standard library implementation is used on macOS. As you found out, [this implementation of `scanf()` function](https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdio/vfscanf.c#L467) does not support `m` extension.

The `m` extension was most probably first implemented in GNU C library. I see it was added in Issue 7 to [POSIX scanf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) specification.

Comment: `Isn't there something...` Yes, compiler can do that. Cool point.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm still confused why clang gives a warning about `%ms` expecting `char **` -- is that because clang's scanf warning-generation-system doesn't check whether it is going to link with glibc or a different C standard library?

Comment: `is that because clang's scanf warning-generation-system doesn't check whether it is going to link with glibc or a different C standard library?` Clang does not care. I find it would be a tedious and unnecessary job for a compiler to have a list of all C standard libraries and versions that happen to support %m... Clang just checks `%ms` should have `char**` the end.

Comment: Coming from C#/Java/Python/JavaScript/Haskell background, this divorce of compiler from the runtime is still a bit surprising. I see that C++ has a similar story with libc++/libstdc++/etc.  But now that I think about it more, you can run a java app using any newer JRE. And I can take a C# library compiled by .NET Framework and attempt to run it using mono or dotnet core. Hopefully these are good analogies to help other people approaching C from newer languages.

Comment: `this divorce of compiler from the runtime` while this is valid point, this is not about that. `printf` and `scanf` are just badly designed interfaces, that completely disable any type checking from the compiler, so compilers have to do tricks to enable them.  It's the same as if you have a library in Java with `printf(String format, Object[] objects)` and you would want to check it _on client-side_ if objects are proper type requested from the string. It's the interface, not really the language.

Comment: take care that every version of .Net is incompatible to the others, so you have to install all of them to support all the C# wrote for the various .Net around. I have 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, some with SP1 and so on. About the useful but not standard %ms i removed from my code as I need to port to macOS too.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the compiler warning recognizes the `%ms` syntax, the compiled code does not support it.

Running `man scanf` the BSD manual doesn't document the m character.